# What is the best way to get the boolean value of an expression?

Tags: javascript

**What is the best way to get the boolean value of an expression?**

I usually use `!!`, wonder if there is any reason to use it over Boolean or if it's ok to use either of those.

```
someFunction: function(param){
  var myBoolean = !!param;
}
```

But I can also do:

```
someFunction: function(param){
  var myBoolean = Boolean(expression); 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: I think it's just like `Number(value)` vs `+value`. One is considered easier to read, and the other is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Both do the same usually. They differ in the following points:

- `!!` is only two characters to type
- `Boolean` is explicit and can be understood even by people who don't know the "[`!!` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572)"
- `Boolean` could be overwritten, whereas `!!` is always safe
- `!!` seems to be [better optimised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15335452/1048572)

So use whatever you like better.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following snippets in the consoles of Safari (8.0.5), Chrome (42.0.2311.90), Firefox (34.0.5) and Opera (29.0.1795.47):

With `!!`:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    var a = true;
    a = !!a;
}
time = new Date().getTime() - time;
console.log(time);
```

With `Boolean()`:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    var a = true;
    a = Boolean(a);
}
time = new Date().getTime() - time;
console.log(time);
```

No matter what I set `a` to before using `!!` or `Boolean`, in all browsers `!!` was faster.

In addition to this (as **Bergi** already said in his answer), `Boolean` is just a variable that has to be resolved and can be overwritten, while `!!` cannot be.

`Boolean()` is more reader-friendly though.

So what is actually **better** is a question of opinion, but I would say performance **and** safety together outweigh readability, so I prefer `!!`.